# Classification Html Table in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, math, razor

I have a list of Data the passed into my View

In the view, it currently shows data like this picture - each item in a single row:

[image]

I want to divide the data into 3 columns, like this picture:

[image]

My code is:

```
<table>    
@{           
    foreach (var item in Model)    
    {     
        <tr>    
            <td class="tg-baqh"></td>    
            <td class="tg-baqh">@item.Name</td>    
            <td class="tg-baqh"></td>    
        </tr>  
    }    
}    
</table>
```

My idea for this is as follows, but it is not correct:

```
@{
 var tblTestList = Model.ToList();
 int divide = Model.Count() / 6;
 int mod = Model.Count() % 6 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
 int tablesCount = divide + mod;

 for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
 {

     <table>
         @{
             int rows = (Model.Count() / ((i + 1) * 6)) >= 1 ? 6 : Model.Count() % 6;
             for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
             {
                 <tr>
                     @{ 
                     for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                     {
                     <td class="tg-baqh">@tblTestList[i * 6 + j].Number</td>
                     <td class="tg-baqh">@tblTestList[i * 6 + j].Name</td>
                     <td class="tg-baqh"></td>
                         }
                     }
                 </tr>
             }
         }


     </table>
   }
}
```

There are 72 numbers (data items). I want to divide it into 4 part, with each part having 18 numbers. So: (72 % 18 = 0)

Comment: in that case you need to keep a count of where you're up to in the `items` list, and on every 3rd item you create a new `<tr>` and `<td>`. For all the others you create just a `<td>` The logic not very tricky. What have you tried?

Comment: Hello . There are a list of number from 1 to 72 with their specific Data .
I want to Divide this 72 numbers to the 4 part . each part has 18 number . this 18 number Divide to 3 part across from them . Like this Picture : http://s8.picofile.com/file/8321241442/Untitled.png

Comment: yes, you already said that in your post. But you didn't ask a question or state what problem you're having. You do not appear to have made any attempt to implement your requirement. This site is not a free write-my-code service, we're volunteers and will spend time helping you if it looks like you tried to help yourself first. Did you even try to do this? Above I gave you the idea for the logic you need. If you're still stuck, post your attempt to implement that logic and explain what goes wrong. Then we can talk again. If you want someone to give you the solution ready-made, open your wallet.

Comment: I have been tried some way and it does not any result for me. i think it has a very simple solution's but I don't have any Idea . I think it will be solve with some For loop . i try many way buy I failed . how much should I pay ? Iran is buy cot From USA and we don't have any  PayPal or ... .

If you can Friendly Help me to solve this solution.

Comment: "I have been tried some way"...well show us then. That's all I asked for - some evidence of your own time spent on the problem. And by paying I didn't mean me or anyone on this site. We're _volunteers_. You can find professional programmers elsewhere I imagine. But really it's not necessary for this issue. Show us your best attempt so far, and explain what it outputs. We already know what you wanted it to output, so then we can compare, and help you fix the code.

Comment: There are 72 Number . we have 4 part each part has 18 number . 
so (72 % 18 = 0) . Other Idea of Code I added to the start of this Topic on this moment

Comment: will there always be 72 numbers in total? Or can it change? Will the total always be divisible by 3? Do you always want 4 sections? Or must the code calculate the correct number of equal-sized sections? None of that you have mentioned.

Comment: This Page Always has 72 Number Always has 4 section and always is divisible by 3 . every number has a "title" that it will be show from DataBase.

Comment: in that case, apart from the title (which you didn't show in the picture of your desired result, but you can add it into each cell easily if you desire) my answer below should work for you. Please remember to accept it / upvote it if it helps you - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not 100% clear, I have written answer based on the following assumptions, taken from your example data and description of the problem:

1. There will always be 72 numbers in total
2. There will always be 3 columns.
3. The result will always be divided into 4 equal-sized sections

If we stick to these assumptions, then the solution just involves some fairly simple maths:

```
@for (int i=1; i<Model.Count; i+=(Model.Count/4))
{
  <table>
    @for (int j = i-1; j< (i+(Model.Count/4)-13); j++)
    {       
      <tr>    
        <td class="tg-baqh">@Model[j+12].Name</td>    
        <td class="tg-baqh">@Model[j+6].Name</td>    
        <td class="tg-baqh">@Model[j].Name</td>    
      </tr>  
    }    
  </table>  
  <br/>
}
```

You can go to https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7HG1W to see a working demo.

If these assumptions are invalid, then you should clarify the precise requirement. Any variance is likely to make the solution more complex.

Comment: Mr ADyson Thank you . I want Exactly this and its correct . just , each of this number has a specific Title that its get from Model (item.Title) . 

how should I add it across from this 72 number ?

Comment: What do you mean by "across from", exactly? If you want it in the same cell, just do `>@Model[j].Title` (and similar for the +6 and +12 cells) in each cell.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr ADyson . You are very professional .